# How can I check if a word is in an image source, and replace that word?

Tags: javascript

I would like to replace the words in an image link based on if that word exists in it. My code seems like it would work but is doesn't. Heres my code:

```
 topimg.addEventListener('error', function(){

    if(topimg.src.indexOf('Tee')){
        topimg.src.replace('Tee', 'T-Shirt');
    }
```

Comment: `replace()` does not mutate the original string, it returns the new string. So you need to reassign `src` with the new string

Answer (score 0):

From the [**MDN web docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> *The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.* ...
>
> ***The original string is left unchanged.***

So therefore try:

```
 topimg.addEventListener('error', function() {
    if (topimg.src.indexOf('Tee')) {
        topimg.src = topimg.src.replace('Tee', 'T-Shirt');
    }
    ...
 }
```